# Bootstrapp-vue join two key into a label

Tags: vue.js

Hello friends I want to display my data in bootstrap vue table like this and here is my table:

[image]

and this is my data

```
data: [
        {
          firt_name: 'Jonh',
          last_name: 'cooper',
          birth_day: '10/07/2000',
          major: 'Computer Scient' 
        },
        {
          firt_name: 'Devid',
          last_name: 'yang',
          birth_day: '05/08/1998',
          major: 'Computer Scient'
        }
      ]
```

please help me if you know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be `<td>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</td>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Birth Date</th>
    <th>Major</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> {{first_name}} {{last_name}}</td>
    <td> {{birth_day}} </td>
    <td> {{major}} </td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```